# What is this strange monument near Bamberg Altenburg?

Tags: germany, identify-this, landmarks, bavaria

I was recently in Bamberg (north-west Bavaria), and when visiting Altenburg I've stumbled upon this strange monument:

[image: Bamberg Altenburg monument]

What can it be? What purpose does it have? Decorative (sculpture)? Ritual (Abalakumba cult ^^)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Beside [another picture on Panoramio](https://ssl.panoramio.com/photo/42195011), I only found this paragraph in german on the [Bamberg site](http://goo.gl/QH1IFV), which refers to a *Steinobelisk* near the castle:

> Neben dem unweit der Burg befindliche Grab von A. F. Marcus lässt sich
>   auch ein Steinobelisk  aus dem Jahr 1903 finden, der eine besondere
>   Botschaft vermittelt. In östlicher Richtung gelegen, befindet er sich
>   auf einem kleinen Plateau. Darin sind Steine aus den Gebieten der
>   einzelnen Ämter des ehemaligen Hochstifts Bamberg verbaut und soll
>   daher an die hundertjährige Zugehörigkeit zum Land (damals noch
>   Königreich) Bayern erinnern.

A translation:

> Next to the grave of A. F. Marcus (not far from the castle), additionally a stone obelisk from the year 1903 can be found.  It conveys an unusual message.  Lying east, it is situated on a small plateau.  In it, stones from the regions of the individual counties of the former [Hochstift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochstift) Bamberg are constructed, and should therefore remind of the 100-year belonging to the country (then still a kingdom) of Bavaria.